# Ubuntu 14 mount cdrom

Tags: mount, fstab

I am trying to mount a cdrom with Ubuntu 14. I have read a lot of guides now and none of them work. Here is my `/etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=a65fb62d-3963-421c-800f-ab8f31ae8ce8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=B93B-E789  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=51c0ac58-9c53-48b8-add2-95593c6a1f93 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

and here is the results from `sudo ls /dev/sr*`:

```
/dev/sr0
```

and here is the results of `sudo lshw -C disk`:

```
*-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: TOSHIBA MK5076GS
       vendor: Toshiba
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: GS00
       serial: 52TBT2NPT
       size: 465GiB (500GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=44291ab4-bda0-4b1c-bda8-00ecf4172451 sectorsize=512
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVDRAM GT50N
       vendor: hp
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: MP01
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

Will someone tell me how to mount my cdrom with that information? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just do `sudo mkdir /media/cdrom && sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom`. Do `ls /media/cdrom` to see its contents.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I solved it now. I am transferring files form an older laptop running Ubuntu 12 to a newer laptop running Ubuntu 14. The older laptop is generating errors in the burning process. When I used Brasero no errors were reported. When I used K3B, errors were reported. The problem isn't mounting. It is burning the disks on the older laptop. The disks are bad or the burning process is. Thanks again for answering though. Really appreciated.